# Pyramid static asset specification without package

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to make a simple pyramid app without using the scaffold generator. The code consists of a single app.py file.

The question is: since app.py is not a part of a package, how do I specify a directory as a static asset specification? I understand an absolute path can always be used, but can I use a path relative to the app.py file?

The following seems to work correctly when the app is run with `wsgiref.simple_server` but is it guaranteed to work in all cases (e.g. when deployed with mod_wsgi or uwsgi?)

```
config.add_static_view('static', 'static')
```

Comment: While I cannot answer your question with a guarantee: What is wrong with creating the 'simple' scaffold and quickly dropping everything you don't need? If your app is **really** simple, you could create a one-file app, but I would like to know what the problem is with using the simple scaffold. Side note: If you only want to build something quickly I found [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to be the better way (personal opinion).

Comment: @javex My problem is not with scaffolds per se, but with the way the generated app is bound to a package name. E.g. if I generate MyApp then the package `myapp` is referred to in multiple places in the source code and configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [pyramid.config](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/config.html#module-pyramid.config) API documentation:

> The path argument is the path on disk where the static files reside. This can be an absolute path, a package-relative path, or a asset specification.

Furthermore, I have looked into the Pyramid sources and it doesn't seem that it depends on the WSGI used in any way. So from my point of view it seems it will always treat this as a relative path to the calling script. It depends on where the Configurator was placed or which script gets executed which is generally the same.

So I conclude that it should work with any WSGI compliant system.

Comment: You are correct, I tried to run the app under uwsgi and the static asset specifications indeed correctly resolved relative to the location of the app.py file. No package specification necessary!